# Изменить шаблон для миграции yii2. Change view for migration yii2

Tags: yii2, миграция, php5

Пытаюсь изменить шаблон для миграции в yii2. Для этого переопределяю MigrateController внутри папки console/controllers вот так:

```
namespace console\controllers;

class MigrateController extends \yii\console\controllers\MigrateController
{
    public $templateFile = __DIR__ .'/../views/migration.php';
}
```

Понятно, что по маршруту `__DIR__ .'/../views/migration.php'` лежит новый шаблон. Но yii2 не видит моего переопределения. Похоже, где-то нужно явно изменить карту отслеживаемых контроллеров. Но где?

Использую шаблон yii2 advanced.

Comment: Возможно и не нужно контроллером это делать. вот посмотрите тут про новый шаблон для миграции: http://yiiframework.ru/doc/guide/ru/database.migration  .... а может вы контроллер не так вызываете.. не с тем неймспейсом,  к примеру.

Comment: Вы дали ссылку на yii1, а я использую yii2. В имени все правильно. Рядом лежит контроллер, который нормально работает.

Comment: суть та же. глобальных настроек должно хватать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Суть по сравнению с `yii1` практически ничем не отличается.

Вы делаете шаблон. Затем прописываем глобальные конфигурации для консольного приложения. При запуске команды `migrate` эти настройки будут применены без ввода каких-либо дополнительных параметров.

Пример.

Создадим шаблон миграции по пути
`migration/templates/mg.php`
Выглядит так:

```
<?php
/**
 * This view is used by console/controllers/MigrateController.php
 * The following variables are available in this view:
 */
/* @var $className string the new migration class name */

echo "<?php\n";
?>

use yii\db\Migration;

class <?= $className ?> extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        $tableOptions = null;
        if ($this->db->driverName === 'mysql') {
            // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/766809/whats-the-difference-between-utf8-general-ci-and-utf8-unicode-ci
            $tableOptions = 'CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE=InnoDB';
        }


    }

    public function down()
    {
        echo "<?= $className ?> cannot be reverted.\n";

        return false;
    }

    /*
    // Use safeUp/safeDown to run migration code within a transaction
    public function safeUp()
    {
    }

    public function safeDown()
    {
    }
    */
}
```

затем в `config/console.php` пишем настройки:

```
return [
...

    'controllerMap' => [
        'migrate' => [
            'class' => 'yii\console\controllers\MigrateController',
            'templateFile' => '@app/migrations/templates/mg.php',
        ],
    ],

...
];
```

Этого достаточно.
Если хотите сделать уж свой контроллер, тогда как пример:

сам контроллер

```
<?php
namespace app\components;

use yii\db\Schema;
use yii\db\Migration;

class MGMigration extends Migration{

}
```

шаблон, по вашему пути.. например `migrations/templates/mg.php`

```
<?php
echo "<?php\n";
?>

use yii\db\Schema;
use yii\db\Migration;
use app\components\MGMigration;

class <?= $className ?> extends MGMigration {

    public function safeUp() {

    }

    public function safeDown() {

    }
}
```

и опять же глобальные настройки в `config/console.php`

```
'controllerMap' => [
        'migrate' => [
            'class' => 'yii\console\controllers\MigrateController',
            'migrationTable' => 'mg_migration',
            'templateFile' => '@app/migrations/templates/mg.php'
        ],
    ],
```

Comment: Спасибо! Поправьте опечатку migration/ на migrationS/